# Thingsboard Upload Converter with multiple timestamps

Tags: iot, thingsboard

My device takes measuremets more often than it communicates with MQTT broker, so there can be more than one timestamb in each message, like this:

```
my/device/telemetry 1651396728000:22,13;1651400328000:25,10;...so on
```

I want to use built-in [Thingsboard MQTT Integration](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/integrations/mqtt/) with my custom Upload Converter, but I can't find proper format for `result` object with multiple timestamps in it (how it was in [Gateway Telemetry API](https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/reference/gateway-mqtt-api/#telemetry-upload-api))

Answer (score 0):

The output of your data converter should be an array like this:

```js
var result = [
{
    "deviceName": "88888888",
    "deviceType": "tracker",
    "attributes": {
        "att1": "val1",
    },
    "telemetry": {
        "ts": 1652738915000,
        "values": {
            "blah": "blooo",
            "External Voltage": 12812
        }
    }
},
{same},
{similar}
]
```